# Ping decreases while i unplug my laptop from power but increases when i plug it back in

Tags: laptop, battery, ping

So I use a HP gaming laptop ,I play ethernet and when i unplug my power cable from the laptop my ping goes down in between 1 and 10 and when i plug it back in i get between 20 and 30 ping, I really don´t know why , I´ve tried looking for em interference, since i read that from a differnet post nut didn´t fix my problem at all,I play fortnite in which ping can make a drastic difference so I´d be realy thankful if someone could help me.

Comment: You see a difference between 1/100 of a second performance difference?  Are you getting these pings from a wireless adapter or an ethernet adapter?

Comment: The difference in ping changes instantly I´m not sure if that was your first questioin , and I´m using a ethernet adapter

Comment: You do understand that a 10 ms improvement is 1/100 of a second?  I would agree that this is likely due to EMI, which isn't something you can "identify" or "locate" it simply exists or doesn't exist, and likely is a design flaw.  What is the health of the battery like? (There is a reason I am asking that question)

Comment: How can I check the my battery health if there´s a way, I´ve had my laptop for around 2 years if that information helps, I know a 10 to 20 ms difference isn´t crazy but I play the game competively and ping really makes a difference, thanks for respoding to my question by the way.

Comment: @Ramhound are you there?